# Initializing std::vector with a repeating pattern

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stdvector

I'm working with OpenGL at the moment, creating a 'texture cache' which handles loading images and buffering them with OpenGL. In the event an image file can't be loaded it needs to fall back to a default texture which I've hard-coded in the constructor.

What I basically need to do is create a texture of a uniform colour. This is not too difficult, it's just an array of size Pixels * Colour Channels.

I am currently using a std::vector to hold the initial data before I upload it OpenGL. The problem I'm having is that I can't find any information on the best way to initialize a vector with a repeating pattern.

The first way that occurred to me was to use a loop.

```
std::vector<unsigned char> blue_texture;
for (int iii = 0; iii < width * height; iii++)
{
    blue_texture.push_back(0);
    blue_texture.push_back(0);
    blue_texture.push_back(255);
    blue_texture.push_back(255);
}
```

However, this seems inefficient since the vector will have to resize itself numerous times. Even if I reserve space first and perform the loop it's still not efficient since the contents will be zeroed before the loop which means two writes for each unsigned char.

Currently I'm using the following method:

```
struct colour {unsigned char r; unsigned char g; unsigned char b; unsigned char a;};
colour blue = {0, 0, 255, 255};
std::vector<colour> texture((width * height), blue);
```

I then extract the data using:

```
reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(texture.data());
```

Is there a better way than this? I'm new to C/C++ and I'll be honest, casting pointers scares me.

Comment: The `reserve` does not zero the `vector`.  Really, how performance critical is this buffer generation?  The degree of optimization you want to do will depend on that a lot.  "I want it to be as fast as possible" is a bad answer, because the fastest code is almost always going to be harder to maintain, more bug prone, etc.  You are best spending effort optimizing the parts that are actually performance critical: optimization is fungible, spending it on non-performance critical code makes your program slower!

Comment: Ideally it needs to be as quick as possible.The program displays a loading screen on startup. Since the loading screen is itself a texture it cannot be loaded and displayed until the texture cache object has initialized.

Comment: Yes, but is this measurably a problem at present?

Comment: Zeroing speed shouldn't be a problem. The CPU should be able to zero RAM at gigabytes per second.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your loop solution is the right way to go in my opinion. To make it efficient by removing repeated realloc calls, use `blue_texture.reserve(width * height * 4)`

The reserve call will increase the allocation, aka capacity to that size without zero-filling it. (Note that the operating system may still zero it, if it pulls the memory from mmap for example.) It does not change the size of the vector, so push_back and friends still work the same way.

Comment: ...and if that's not enough, you could look into SIMD for writing sixteen bytes at a time with a single instruction.

Comment: @Cameron Shouldn't a smart compiler do that for me?

Comment: @leemes: It can't unless it knows that the target architecture is guaranteed to support SSE2 (or what have you). Generally you have to write the intrinsics by hand, and branch at runtime between the two implementations to achieve portability. It might not do vectorization in general because that requires much more work than a simple loop -- unrolling the first and last few iterations in order to have aligned data, etc. You wouldn't want that applied to *every* vectorizable loop... :-)

Comment: @Cameron You're right, but if you select the appropriate architecture and optimization level, it is done by most smart compilers. Of course, the branch remains to be done when you want to support older hardware (at least I don't know of an easy general solution to just "kick in" like a compiler option / directive).

Answer (score 3):

The most efficient way is the way that does least work.

Unfortunately, push_back(), insert() and the like have to maintain the size() of the vector as they work, which are redundant operations when performed in a tight loop.

Therefore the most efficient way is allocate the memory once and then copy data directly into it without maintaining any other variables.

It's done like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>

using colour_fill = std::array<uint8_t, 4>;
using pixel_map = std::vector<uint8_t>;

pixel_map make_colour_texture(size_t width, size_t height, colour_fill colour)
{
    // allocate the buffer
    std::vector<uint8_t> pixels(width * height * sizeof(colour_fill));

    auto current = pixels.data();
    auto last = current + pixels.size();

    while (current != last) {
        current = std::copy(begin(colour), end(colour), current);
    }

    return pixels;
}

auto main() -> int
{
    colour_fill blue { 0, 0, 255, 255 };
    auto blue_bits = make_colour_texture(100, 100, blue);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reserve` to pre-allocate the vector; this will avoid the reallocations. You can also define a small sequence (probably a C style vector:

```
char const init[] = { 0, 0, 255, 255 };
```

and loop inserting that into the end of the vector:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < pixelCount; ++ i ) {
    v.insert( v.end(), std::begin( init ), std::end( init ) );
}
```

this is only marginally more efficient than using the four `push_back` in the loop, but is more succinct, and perhaps makes it clearer what you're doing, albeit only marginally: the big advantage might be being able to give a name to the initialization sequence (eg something like `defaultBackground`).

Comment: what's `v` in the above?

Answer (score 0):

I would reserve the entire size that you need and then use the insert function to repeatedly add the pattern into the vector.

```
std::array<unsigned char, 4> pattern{0, 0, 255, 255};
std::vector<unsigned char> blue_texture;
blue_texture.reserve(width * height * 4);

for (int i = 0; i < (width * height); ++i)
{
    blue_texture.insert(blue_texture.end(), pattern.begin(), pattern.end());
}
```

Comment: I think you've got the order of the arguments in `blue_texture.insert` wrong. (I'd also use a C style array, rather than `std::array` here. No need to have to explicitly state the 4.)

Comment: @JamesKanze You are correct I had the insert position in the wrong spot.

Answer (score 0):

I made this template function which will modify its input container to contain `count` times what it already contains.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename Container>
void repeat_pattern(Container& data, std::size_t count) {
  auto pattern_size = data.size();
  if(count == 0 or pattern_size == 0) {
    return;
  }
  data.resize(pattern_size * count);
  const auto pbeg = data.begin();
  const auto pend = std::next(pbeg, pattern_size);
  auto it = std::next(data.begin(), pattern_size);
  for(std::size_t k = 1; k < count; ++k) {
    std::copy(pbeg, pend, it);
    std::advance(it, pattern_size);
  }
}

template<typename Container>
void show(const Container& data) {
  for(const auto & item : data) {
    std::cout << item << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4};
  repeat_pattern(v, 3);
  // should show three repetitions of times 1, 2, 3, 4
  show(v);
}
```

Output (compiled as `g++ example.cpp -std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra`):

```
1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4
```